# Do multiple axons innervate a single skeletal muscle fiber?

Tags: muscles, central-nervous-system

The typical text-book illustration of innervation of muscle fibers shows branches at a single position along the fiber. Does any given muscle fiber have more axons that innervate it though, given that muscle cells can be quite long, up to half a meter in Sartorius?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Until a better educated person contributes a more detailed answer, Hunt's article here from 1954 will likely be the best source,

> *studies have shown that muscle fibres in the frog's sartorius are innervated in two major zones and most of the fibres receive motor
>   endings at at least two regions along their length (Katz & Kuffler,
>   1941). In this case a multiply-innervated muscle fibre may derive its
>   several end-plates from the same motor nerve fibre. The possibility
>   also exists that a muscle fibre may receive end-plates from more than
>   one nerve fibre, i.e. polyneuronal innervation.*

HUNT CC, KUFFLER SW. Motor innervation of skeletal muscle: multiple innervation of individual muscle fibres and motor unit function. J Physiol. 1954;126(2):293–303. doi:10.1113/jphysiol.1954.sp005210

He in turn references an article by Kats and Kuffler from 1941,

KATZ, B. & KUFFLER, S. W. (1941). Multiple motor innervation of the frog's sartorius muscle. J. Neurophysiol. 4, 209-223.

As those are both 70 years old, it is likely that more documentation has been produced, and that it could contribute to a competent answer to the question.